# Iterate over nested (multi-dimensional) hashmap

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap<String, Object>` that looks like this when I call .toString() on it:

```
{somekey=false, anotherKey=someString, thirdKey={nestedKey=hello, nestedKey2=world,etc=etcetcetc}}
```

At a certain point in my script, I would like to iterate over the "thirdKey" set as its own map. Is there a common convention used to isolate a "nested" HashMap and use it as its own one-dimensional map?

Comment: In other words, you'd like to "flatten" the whole map for iteration?

Comment: how many levels of nested maps could exist in your data?

Comment: just the 2 levels - as shown in the example

Comment: then it is not that difficult.. wait let me give you a snippet. but I would serioosuly recommend from this code create a recursive data definition which can detect multiple levels of nested levels and flatten the map for you.

I think I don't have to write my anwer.. `Bohemian` already did that for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my code for recursively extracting all values from the map (and the maps within these map).

```
public List<Object> getValues(Map<String, Object> map) {

    List<Object> retVal = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Object value = entry.getValue();

        if (value instanceof Map) {
            retVal.addAll(getValues((Map) value));
        } else {
            retVal.add(value);
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

As Vikdor already said, I don't think there is a real convention for this.

**Edit:**
You could, of course, also write the keys and values into a new Map ("flattening" it). I just added the values to a List, because this way you don't run into problems when one of the nested maps uses an already present key.

Answer (score 3):

No convention I'm aware of. You have to fall back to `instanceof` to see if the value at the key is a `Map`, and treat it specially if it is - in your case recursively.

Comment: I was writing that answer but you already wrote it. good one. I was also suggesting that dont consider it to be just two levels. design it in such a way that it can handle multiple levels.

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah yes - i've done exactly this recently to mimic the way javascript/json works

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if there would be a "*common convention*" with generics in place. It's best to move towards strongly typed programs and not use Object as either key or value of a hashmap. Then this scenario won't be encountered and one would have more organized data definitions. My two cents!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> tempMap = flatten((HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue());
            for (Entry<String, Object> tempEntry : tempMap.entrySet()) {
                newMap.put(entry.getKey()+"."+tempEntry.getKey(), tempEntry.getValue());
            }
        } else {
            newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return newMap;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Anyway: I am unsure what the additional value of your answer is because it seems like a slightly modified copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12143746/1251613). So you should also explain what your added value is. Otherwise I think the answer should be flagged as "Not an answer".